# Iterate Json object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have below JSON and I want to iterate it through javascript. How do I do it.

```
var data= {"key1":[{"alfa":"abcd","a":"a1","b":"b1","c":"c1","d":"d1"},
     {"number":"1234","1":"11","22":"2","3":"33","4":"44"}],

      "key2":[{"alfa":"abcd","a":"a1","b":"b1","c":"c1","d":"d1"},
     {"number":"1234","1":"11","2":"22","3":"33","4":"44"}]}
```

DS Used: Map of String,List of Object

Comment: what want you do with the data?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object

Answer (score 1):

```
Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
  for(let item of data[key]){
    Object.keys(item).forEach(key => {
      console.log(item[key]) // do stuff here
    })
  }
})
```

I'd so something like this

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples how you can access the fields:

```
console.log(data.key1[0].alfa);
console.log(data.key2[0].alfa);
console.log(data.key2[0].a);
```